# Time complexity for Regular Expression Matching

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I was solving the problem Regular Expression Matching on leetcode. I solved it using recursion as below:

```
    if (p.empty())    return s.empty();
    
    if ('*' == p[1])
        // x* matches empty string or at least one character: x* -> xx*
        // *s is to ensure s is non-empty
        return (isMatch(s, p.substr(2)) || !s.empty() && (s[0] == p[0] || '.' == p[0]) && isMatch(s.substr(1), p));
    else
        return !s.empty() && (s[0] == p[0] || '.' == p[0]) && isMatch(s.substr(1), p.substr(1));
```

But in this how can I find the time complexity of the code?

Problem link: https://leetcode.com/problems/regular-expression-matching/

PS: In solution they have explained the time complexity but I could not understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `T(t,p)` is the time complexity of function `isMatch(text, pattern)` where t is `text.length()` and p is `pattern.length() / 2`

First `T(x,0) = 1` for all x

Then if `pattern[1] == '*'`, `T(t,p) = T(t,p-1) + T(t-1,p) + O(t + p)`

Otherwise `T(t,p) = T(t-1, p-0.5) + O(t + p)`

Obviously the first case is worse

Think about the *Combination Meaning* of `T`.
Originally the is a ball you on coordinate `(t,p)`, in one step you can move it to `(t-1,p)` or `(t,p-1)`, costing `t+p`.
The ball stop on axis.
Then `T(t,p)` equals to the total cost of each valid way to move the ball to axis starting from `(t,p)`.

Then we know

[image]

So the total time complexity is `O((t+p)2^(t + p/2))`

BTW your code will run faster if you use something like `std::string_view` instead of `.substr()`, which prevents copying the whole string.